# How should I add a URL into my SQL Case Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error, case

I need to add a URL into my case statement -

```
Case when status='a' then <a href="https://www.google.com/"> Account Status </a>
```

But I keep getting an error

Comment: "keep getting an error" is NEVER a useful thing to post. Whenever you encounter an error, post the complete error message. And a URL is just a string - there is nothing special about it though it might be rendered (i.e., displayed) in a certain manner by various applications that understand what that represents.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the quotes around the string in the `then` clause:

```
Case when status='a' then '<a href="https://www.google.com/"> Account Status </a>'
-- Here ------------------^------------------------------------------------------^
```

You're also missing the `end` keyword, but I'm guessing this is just a truncated part of your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

should be a string :

```
Case when status='a' 
then '<a href="https://www.google.com/"> Account Status </a>'
end
```